# Ler todas as linhas preenchidas VBA

Tags: vba

Bom dia,

Eu preciso ler a quantidade de linhas preenchidas para realizar um for, porem algumas linhas estão em branco e a função para quando encontra a linha em branco

```
col = Worksheets(1).Range("C4").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 1 To col
```

Por ex : a coluna C possui 1129 linhas porem quando vai da linha 259 para 260 a 260 esta vazia e ele retorna somente ate a 259

Poderiam me sugerir alguma alternativa?

Obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro a alternativa de, ao invés de percorrer as células para baixo, selecione uma célula muito além das linhas que você sabe que não estará preenchida e percorrer para cima, exemplo:

```
col = Worksheets(1).Range("C100000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To col
```

Assim, a variável `col` retornará o número da última linha com informações.